# problems in setting bg image according to screen resolution

Tags: html, css, image, resolution

I'm currently developing a website. I'm using an `img` in HTML file with dimensions 1466x530. It works fine on laptop (1366x768) but it is kind of zoomed in desktop (1024x768). Also the pages that were perfect in laptop resolution are zoomed in desktop. Could you help me please.

```
.center-shadow {background:url(../images1/center-shadow.png) center top no-repeat; }
```

Comment: Are you sure the browser is set to 100% zoom?

Comment: Use @media queries in your css and style it seperately for the desktop version.

Comment: text, images and the rest of the content are bound to show up differently on different resolutions, primarily because a website tries to fit itself into the screen resolutions. This is just normal behaviour. As for the image zoom issue, it's not an issue exactly, it's taking up the 1466 * 530 space available to it in pixel per inch of the monitor.

Comment: thanx for your valuable reply :) by the way making the browser zoom to 75 % makes the web pages to get a full view. So do i have to make changes to  all the contents in web page to reduce 25 % or is there any other way to make my web page to full view? Thanx :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes It happens, because 1480x530 is bigger image for 1024 resolution hence it looks zoomed and same goes for fonts which you have sized in pixel units it will tend to look different sizes in different screens.

if you want to show your site in same proportions in all screens you must use Media Query or setup such way it looks best in all screens.

Thanks
Manoj Soni